# We’re sorry. This seller doesn’t accept payments in your currency. Please return to the seller and choose another way to pay in react

Tags: reactjs, paypal

I have integrated react PayPal button to in my react app using live client id but when I am trying to make payment using my PayPal account it is showing error `We’re sorry. This seller doesn’t accept payments in your currency. Please return to the seller and choose another way to pay.`.

Searched a lot in google but did not found any helpful source.

Please if you have clue about this kindly help me, struggling for the last 3 days.

Thanks in advance for you any help.

Comment: check currency setting in for paypal account : Log in to your PayPal account.
Click Money at the top of the page -> Click Manage Currency.

Answer (score 0):

For instance AFAIK there is one possible reason for such an error:

1. for some countries (e.g. Russian Federation) there is an internal
   law avoiding payments in other currency rather than russian rouble
   between russian residents.
2. in this case if payer and payee are both russian residents , payment
   won't work if price for product or service is set in USD/EUR .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like India and Russia have similar restrictions regarding to domestic payment currencies. There are some [recommendations](https://www.paypalobjects.com/digitalassets/c/website/marketing/apac/IN/enable-inr-for-merchants/enabling-inr-payments-direct-website-ec.pdf) for India which are useful for Russia as well.
To test that your integration works correctly in case of an international buyer, you may want to create one more sandbox personal PayPal account (with US country of origin). Then you'll be able to invoice and accept payments from both Russian buyer (in rubles) and US buyer (in USD).